# GCP OAuth Consent Screen - Show custom data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I have a Firebase Application on GCP where I wish to enable Google login.
The login works, but I wish to show my app name and contact email on login instead of the default "Authorized domain".

If my default authorized domain is `myapp-dev.firebaseapp.com` and my website is `app.myapp.com` ---> I wish for the OAuth Consent Screen to show `app.myapp.com`.

I have tried to follow both below guides, but none works.
[Guide 1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#expandable-4)
[Guide 2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#setredirecturi)

Adding a CNAME as described in **Guide 1** breaks my application since it redirects all traffic to Firebase hosting. My site is hosted outside GCP.

My OAuth Consent Screen (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent?project=xxxx) shows no options and only says:

> **Verification status**
> Verification not required
>
> Your consent screen is being shown, but your app has not been reviewed
> so your users may not see all of your information, and you will not be
> able to request certain OAuth scopes.

How can I change the OAuth Consent Screen?

Kind regards /K

Answer (score 0):

It seems the documentation has **missed to mention** the "EDIT APP" link on top of the page
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent?project=xxx !

After clicking this link - I managed to edit the "OAuth consent Screen"!

/K